# How to use both built-in speakers and external microphone on a single jack?

Tags: pulseaudio, skype

I would like to use built-in speakers of my laptop *and* an external microphone in the same time (for skype).

*But* my sound card has only one connector which does both output and input. So when I plug in my microphone, pulseaudio deactivate automatically the speakers (which are seen as "unavailable" in pavucontrol).

How to use both built-in speakers and external microphone on a single jack?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but it is still a pain to configure. Luckily since then PulseAudio evolved (yes, you have to use PulseAudio). To do so:

```
apt install pulseaudio
```

then you can:

```
pacmd list-sources | grep -e device.string -e 'name:'
```

and you will obtain something like this:

```
name: <alsa_output.platform-soc_audio.analog-mono.monitor>
    device.string = "0"
name: <alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.analog-mono>
    device.string = "hw:1"
```

to set your input (in my case en external usb microphone) you can type:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.analog-mono
```

to make the change permanent, add this line at the end of your `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00.analog-mono
```

The same apply for your output:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index'
```

in my case I am using the internal audio device (I'm on a RPi3):

```
* index: 2
name: <alsa_output.platform-soc_audio.analog-mono>
```

and, like before:

```
pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.platform-soc_audio.analog-mono
```

Comment: To use the speakers while a headset is in the audio-jack (not USB), you have to use a command like `pacmd set-sink-port 1 analog-output-speaker`, where 1 is the index of the analog sound (comprising both internal speakers and jack) and analog-output-speaker is the port (found in `pacmd list-sinks`). In theory, this should work for a mic as well, but I have not gotten a mic to work in the combi-jack, as the system thinks it's headphones. There might be some hope using HDAJackRetask from the `alsa-tools-gui` package: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/turn-headphone-jack-microphone-jack-ubuntu